# Is there an elegant way to handle supporting using multiple fonts with a word

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I've just received a brief from a graphic designer who wants to use font-X for most of the text on a webpage,  but has chosen to also use font-Y for certain specific characters (e,k,l,s).

Unless there is a trick I'm unaware of for handling this, this seems like a right pain in the...

If this is a requirement that cannot be changed to say 'single-font per word only',  is there an elegant way to handle this?

From an end-HTML perspective, it seems that the code would need to be something like

```
<div class="use_font_x">
    H<span class="use_font_y">ell</span>o Wor<span class="use_font_y">l</span>d<span class="use_font_y">s</span>
</div>
```

I'm thinking some javascript/jquery could be used to pick up the DOM-elements of font-X and then parse them and add in spans for the special characters that require font-Y ?

Or else maybe there's some CSS directive to indicate what font should be used for specific characters (wishful thinking? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save yourself the pain, I would (let the graphic designer) design a custom fontfile which mixes the two fonts. I can see no other solution without you being in a world of pain ;)

Comment: +1.  Excellent answer, and preserves semantics.  Would add that I would also generate the @font-face package through something like Font Squirrel's generator *and* make sure that there is a decent stack to fallback on for non-supporting browsers.

Comment: thanks, this would indeed be the ideal! i await their response.  @joseph.ferris, when you say 'decent stack to fallback on', do you mean just a well defined font-family CSS attribute? Or something included in the font-face package?

Comment: @econstantin - Yes, a well-defined font-family is indeed what I am referring to. :-)

Comment: @joseph.ferris It should be noted though that the font-face rule is VERY widely accepted: http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face

Comment: @ThomasM - True.  Old habits, and all of that.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are cursed and are not able to use ThomasM's solution try this.  Warning `text` needs to have just text.  It can't have HTML elements in it.

```
text.replace(/[ekls]/ig,'<span class="use_font_y">$&</span>');
```

Comment: thanks, hopefully it won't come to this, but with jquery and some proper css class definitions, it should reasonably easy to apply this method to non HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 does provide for `unicode-range` rules, in which you can designate fonts to use for specific characters. The original intent was to cover mixed language pages and other cases where characters aren't available in a particular font, but could be used here as detailed in http://24ways.org/2011/unicode-range .

As the 24ways article warns, however, this is not currently supported in Firefox or in older versions of Internet Explorer.